# How is the direction of intercept determined?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification, predictive-models

Let's say I have a equation like as below (linear regression)

Y = intercept + x1+x2+x3...xn

intercept = 30

positive coeff sum = 40

negative coeff sum = -10

So, the final outcome becomes like as below

30 + 40 - 10 = 60

My question is why does intercept have to be +30?

It could have been -30 as well?

Whether logistic or linear regression, how is the sign of intercept determined?

Does intercept only take positive values always?

Comment: ?? It doesn't have to be +30 or -30, this is what was estimated from your data, theoretically it could be any value. It doesn't have to be positive.

Comment: Why the [tag:neural-networks] tag? That makes me think you have some other question for which this question is a proxy. Do you know about the [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: It's fine if you removed the [tag:neural-networks] tag because it was a mistake to include it in the first place, but your original inclusion of that tag leads me to wonder if you have some other question for which this is a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

It is determined by the estimation method you select. In OLS, the regression parameters $\hat\beta_{OLS}$ are determined by the following.

$$
\hat\beta_{OLS}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
$$

Whatever the result of that calculation turns out to be is the answer.

Logistic regression does not have a closed-form equation for its parameter vector, but it can be calculated as the parameter vector that minimizes the crossentropy loss function (same as how OLS minimizes the square loss function, which turns out to be the same as the $\hat\beta_{OLS}$ above). Whatever the intercept value is in the parameter vector is the intercept in the logistic regression; any real number is possible.

Comment: is there any logic to this? I ask this because, my input variables explain only 30% of the outcome. And model has predicted the class probability to be 70%. So, intercept is 40..

Comment: @TheGreat Logistic regression has its coefficients calculated a different way, and there is not a closed-form solution like there is in OLS. I gave that as an example of how the intercept is whatever the intercept in the parameter vector is that minimizes the loss function (square loss in OLS). // What do you mean that the input variables explain $30\%$ of the outcome? How do you calculate that? // What do you mean that the predicted class probability is $70\%?$ Is that for one observation? What about the other observations? // Do you mean an intercept of $40$ because $70-30=40?$

Comment: I have put a bounty on the below uestion. If you have time and are interested, can help me with the related question -

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/107928/usefulness-of-intercept-in-layman-terms-eli5

Comment: How are you getting the $30$ and $70?$

Comment: LIME, a explainable AI solution , python package, helps you compute the intercept and sum of coefficients.

Comment: Does LIME not calculate regression coefficients the usual way?

Comment: It calculates the usual way only. Meaning, it uses linear models like linear, logistic, lasso etc to explain the black box models.

Comment: Am not sure whether you had a chance to look at my other post linked above. If you had a look, you can clearly understand on the problem that I am encountering.

Comment: It seems you're trying to make sense of a nonexistent intercept term in a random forest model, which is part of the reason people are not understanding you there or here. However, the random forest approach you take there has no impact on the logistic regression intercept estimate. The logistic regression coefficient is the same, whether you fit a random forest or not.

Comment: No, i am trying to make sense of high intercept returned by linear model to explain the original random forest model

Comment: Then please ask a new question asking exactly that. (Major edits to existing questions are problematic on Cross Validated and probably the other Stacks like DS and AI.)

Comment: I thought my other question in DS explains exactly that (problem am facing).

Answer (score 0):

For linear regression, the intercept can be positive or negative (or 0), and simply represents the value of the mean of Y when the hyperplane (your linear relationship) passes through the point where all of the explanatory variables are 0 (i.e, x=(0,0,...,0).)  If you have data around (0,0,...,0), this point is meaningful, otherwise it's just a starting point for estimating the value of y for any x in your data range and doesn't have much practical value, itself.

For a logistic regression, it can also be positive or negative (or 0).  Being negative, here, means that the probability (e^B0/(1+e^B0)) at x = (0,0,...,0) will be < 0.5 and being positive means that it will be > 0.05.  Again, though, its practical value will depend on whether you are interested in (and have data around) that point.

Side note: I can't tell from the original question whether you are confusing variables and coefficients, and possibly missing that they are two different but required elements.  For example, we might normally see:

y = intercept + B1X1 + B2X2 + ... + BnXn + noise

where each Bi is the coefficient (slope) of the corresponding Xi variable. The intercept is often written as B0.

The sum of the coefficients (your "coeff sum"), then, would only matter if you happened to be looking at the point where all of the X's have a value of 1.  That's a very, very specific case that is rarely of particular interest (even with all binary variables, that's just one particular case.)